# how to have a pop up for email attachment open though our app in iphone.

Tags: ios

Can any one help on, how to have a pop up conformation for email attachment and it should open though our app (attachment should have .html extension).

Comment: chk this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2774343/how-do-i-associate-file-types-with-an-iphone-application or follow this tut http://www.raywenderlich.com/1980/email-tutorial-for-ios-how-to-import-and-export-app-data-via-email-in-your-ios-app

Answer (score 1):

It should be pretty straight forward. Use [MFMailComposeViewController](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MessageUI/Reference/MFMailComposeViewController_class/Reference/Reference.html)